# Passing json data from resolve to controller ui-router

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to angular, so sorry for the newbish question, but I'm totally stumped.

I am trying to preload my controller with data when the route changes using using `resolve`.  I am getting data back from the server, and I'm injecting the resolve object into the controller, but something isn't working.

Here is the resolve portion of the ui-router

```
resolve: {
    categoryList: function ($http) {
        $http.get('cfc/category.cfc?method=getCategories')
            .success(function (data) {
                return data;
            });
    }
},...
```

and the controller

```
app.controller('CategoryController', ['$scope', '$http', 'categoryList', 
    function ($scope, $http, categoryList) {...
```

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minor little detail:

```
resolve: {
    categoryList: function ($http, $q) {
        var defObj = $q.defer();
        $http.get('cfc/category.cfc?method=getCategories')
            .success(function (data) {
                defObj.resolve(data);
            });
        return defObj.promise;
    }
},...
```

What's happening is that your promise is resolving AFTER your controller has loaded, which means that your data was not passed in. By adding the deferred object and returning it, you get the promised data injected into your controller AFTER it resolves, and everything should be good. Also, you may want to handle the $http call failure with an error handler and insert some dummy data that you can detect and react to in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `$http` returns a promise by default so all you have to do is
`javascript
return $http.get( ...`